# Rust cargo cannot find postgres package

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I have this in `Cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies.postgres]

git = "https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres.git"
```

This resulted in the following output, when running `cargo build`:

```
$ cargo build -u
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres.git`
No package named `postgres` found (required by `hello-world`).
Location searched: https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres.git
Version required: *
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `[dependencies.postgres]` `[dependencies.rust-postgres]`

The reason for this is: [Cargo.toml](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/blob/master/Cargo.toml) of that package is defines the package name as `rust-postgres`, and this needs to match.

Note however, that it also defines the name of its `lib` as just `postgres`.
So you would do `extern crate postgres;`(**not** `extern crate rust-postgres;`)